Health Connect in Android widgets
I have a question that I haven't been able to resolve yet. It's related to Health Connect in a widget. The problem is that Health Connect allows data retrieval only in the foreground. So, if I try to get, for example, the number of steps in a widget/WorkManager/Job/Service every 15-30 minutes, I catch an exception:
java.lang.SecurityException: android.health.connect.HealthConnectException: java.lang.SecurityException: XXXXX must be in foreground to call aggregate method
This confirms what is described in the technical documentation:
enter image description here
One workaround is to request access to ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, then start a foreground service from the widget and retrieve all the information there. But we understand that not all users will grant access to ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS.
Has anyone encountered this problem? So far, it doesn't look very appealing compared to Google Fit, which allows data updates from the background, etc.
UPDATE:
Looks like answer to my question is here https://www.androidpolice.com/android-phones-health-hub-getting-key-upgrades-later-this-year/
Health Connect will soon allow apps to read data in the background

